# Stuck successfully completing an early gang takeover in Saints Row 3

Tags: saints-row-the-third

I've barely begun the PC version of Saints Row the Third - and I simply cannot get past this part where I have to get rid of a gang operation comprising a huge bunch of crooks in an open park area. Wave after wave of gangsters and helicopter mounted snipers keep spawning and I get killed off.

How do I get past this part?

Comment: What part is it? Can you be more specific?

Comment: You don't have to do the city takeovers.  You can just do all of the activities/buy all properties in the area for the same effect. Takeovers just give you the benefit of completing every activity/owning each property (discounts and cash flow iirc) without actually doing them.

Comment: easiest way of doing a takeover is to use a reaper drone

Comment: The very beginning of the game storyline, when they have to take over the whole city again. You meet with Pierce, then buy a gun store and an apartment block, then have to go to a gang operation, except there's way too many of them, and more keep showing up in cars.

Comment: @turbo - but if you're playing the campaign, then aren't you supposed to finish the part? Each time I die, I have to again start with buying the shops.

Comment: I don't remember that part being that hard, as long as you kill the 'marked' gang members then the mission moves onto the next stage.  You don't need to go after the spawning waves.

Comment: But they come after you, not to mention the helicopter sniping from above. If I stop to shoot the helicopter, I get killed by the others

Comment: Ohh you're talking about a gang operation, a takeover is different.  I haven't played since the game came out, and I don't remember having any trouble with this.  You don't have to kill reinforcements, so don't focus on them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the deal:

I had the same problem with this mission; which is crazy, since it's like one of the first ones you do!

The secret is to stay in a car for as long as possible.  You can shoot your gun while sitting in (relative) safety from the car.  The other point to make (thanks @spartacus) is only killing the marked gang members.  Once you wipe out the marked members, drive to the next area and again remain in the safety of your car.  The car you start out with will have a very high tolerance to damage, and if it happens to light on fire, get out and steal a new car!  As an added precaution, try to park your car in such a way to block the sight lines of the snipers.  This is hard, but the first area allows you to park the car in the little alley and shoot the gang members, and will prevent those darn snipers from drawing a bead on you for a little while.